# How can I get Hibernate to map nvarchar and ntext?

Tags: sql-server-2008, hibernate, sql-server-2005, jpa-2.0, nvarchar

I've inherited a project that uses SQLServer 2008 (and maybe 2005).  Certain tables use nvarchar(255) and nvarchar(MAX) which Hibernate can't deal with.  I've tried these proposed solutions:

[How can Hibernate map the SQL data-type nvarchar(max)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099413/how-can-hibernate-map-the-sql-data-type-nvarcharmax)

http://blog.cherouvim.com/sql-server-hbm2ddl-unicode-columns/

They don't work with nvarchar(MAX), unfortunately.  I get this Exception

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in MTP.dbo.Impact
edDetail for column Message. Found: ntext, expected: nvarchar(255)
```

The remaining problem is getting one of these solutions to work with nvarchar(MAX).

Is there a way to make Hibernate work with these unicode column types?  If Hibernate won't work I can switch to another JPA provider that knows how to handle them properly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to handle nvarchar(MAX) by using the @Lob annotation on the corresponding field in the Entity class while also used the SqlServerNativeDialect class in the link above.