# Hibernate native sql query

Tags: sql, hibernate, native

Perfectly fine ms-sql statement

```
SELECT distinct ProductLineCode ,
(SELECT CAST(ItemName + ', ' AS VARCHAR(MAX)) FROM Product spt 
where spt.ProductLineCode = pt.ProductLineCode FOR XML PATH ('')) 
as ItemNames FROM Product pt where ProductLineCode is not null
```

cause error when executed as native query in hibernate.

org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -16

I guess that JDBC type: -16 is boolean but that says me nothing. Product table has xml mapping and works well for months.
Could you please guide me what to try next?

Comment: Lokks like it can'rt add proper Java type for some DB type. (may be the VARCHAR( MAX)). Try to play with result types of the query's columns

Comment: Removing AS VARCHAR(MAX)  cause org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter -17190 [main]  - SQL Error: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter -17191 [main]  - Incorrect syntax near 'CAST', expected 'AS'.

Comment: Try another type. e.g. VARCHAR(100)

Answer (score 2):

You might as advised in comments be able to get something similar to work by changing the types in the sql.

But if that doesn't bring success, you might also be able to tell hibernate how to deal with this type by changing the `Dialect` class used by your application, possibly even extending the one currently used and adding a registration for the missing type.

It appears that your missing type mapping is for the type `java.sql.Types.LONGNVARCHAR` (by code grep, the value is -16), so a `Dialect` extension with a call something like

```
registerColumnType( Types.LONGNVARCHAR, "text" );
```

in the constructor may convince hibernate to treat this field as text.

If you do this you'll have to change the configuration to use your dialect by modifying the line

```
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect</property>
```

to use your own dialect class.  (Note: the class in there is just a guess at what you might have there now.)

It's also possible that you just have hibernate using the wrong dialect for your DB, in which case just changing the configuration to the appropriate one would be better.

It's rarely necessary to use a custom `Dialect`, but this may be one of those times.

Comment: I can't find any alternative for ms SQL server dialect  <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>

Comment: Thanks Don. Where exactly I may register Column type?

Comment: Which dialects are available will depend on your version of hibernate, and which is appropriate depends of course on the version of your DB.

Comment: Just add the `registerColumnType` call to your dialog extension's constructor.

Comment: I've just noticed this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099413/how-can-hibernate-map-the-sql-data-type-nvarcharmax) which may also be useful.

Comment: public class CustomSQLServerDialect extends SQLServerDialect{
  public CustomSQLServerDialect(){
            super();
            registerColumnType( Types.LONGNVARCHAR, "text" );
            registerColumnType(Types.VARCHAR, "nvarchar($l)");
            registerColumnType(Types.CLOB, "nvarchar(max)"); 
     }
} Make sure that custom dialect been loaded by setting breakpoint. Same mapping exception. 8(((