# Change Hibernate's default SQL type for String

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I want to enable schema validation against an existing database on startup using the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate` property.

However, pretty much all of the String column definitions are failing that validation:

```
Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [displayName] in table [MY_TABLE];
found [nvarchar (Types#NVARCHAR)], but expecting [varchar(255) (Types#VARCHAR)]
```

Example field definition:

```
@Column(name = "display_name")
private String displayName;
```

The target schema has over 100 tables with up to 50 columns each, changing the `columnDefinition` to `nvarchar` for every String field is not feasible.

Can the default SQL type for `String` be changed from `varchar(255)` to `nvarchar`?

Comment: i think it is better to search and replace, as to reprogram hibernate

Comment: Possibly related: [How can Hibernate map the SQL data-type nvarchar(max)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1099413/12567365) - can you use `columnDefinition = "nvarchar"` or `@Nationalized` here? There are other approaches suggested also.

Comment: Yes, I could use `columnDefinition = "nvarchar"`, but as I pointed out, then I'd have to find and replace 5000 fields, with different field names, column names and schema properties.

Comment: Right - apologies, I did not read carefully. (FWIW, I agree with nbk, even tho you mention it's not feasible - I take your word for it.)

Comment: No worries :) I managed to rewrite all fields, using IntelliJ's `Search structurally...` feature

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this using IntelliJ's `Search structurally...` feature to rewrite all 5000+ fields.